# Red Error message without loading a new page and alert box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to have neat way of giving error to users by giving them a error message if any of the field in forms are empty right in front of the field. I want to restrain myself from using alert boxes.
My code is:-

```
  function validateform(){
    var x=document.class["validatefname"].value
    if (x==NULL || x == ""){
  alert("First name cannot be blank");
  return false;
    }
  }

  </script>
  <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="15" maxlength="20" value=""/> </p>
  <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" size="15" maxlength="30" value=""/> </p>
  <p>Customer Telephone Number: <input type="text" name="ctn" size="15" maxlength="10" value=""/> </p>
  <p>Term <select name="term">
 <option value="noterm">No Term</option>
 <option value="1year">1 Year</option>
 <option value="2year">2 Year</option>
 <option value="3year">3 Year</option>
   </select></p>
   <p>Selling Price: <input type="text" name="sprice" size="15" maxlength="20" value=""/> </p>
   <p>Enter IMEI: <input type="text" name="simei" size="15" maxlength="20" value=""/> </p>
   <p><input type="submit"name="submit" value="Post Sale" onclick="validateform();"/></p>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sure, I can do php validation but can the error messages appear through PHP without reloading the page and without changing the page.

Comment: No. If you decide to do it in the client, do it on the server as well. Otherwise users can bypass the validation by turning off js.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom thanks for the info i never thought like this. helpful & great tip..

Answer (score 0):

http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/how-validate-forms-both-sides-using-php-jquery/

both javascript and php validation is explained here.